# key charCode for virtual keyboard

Tags: javascript, mobile

I have the below code to allow the user input only numbers, this works in browser. But when I access on mobile I think I am not able to get the right key code. So what are the keycodes for the same. Isn't same as the web.

```
  // block e char, dot, hiphen and spacebar
  if (event.key === 'e' || [46, 45, 32].includes(event.charCode)) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }else{
   // allow to input logic
}
```

What are the charCode for dot, hyphen and space which will work for both web and mobile keypad ?

Comment: Why use `key` for `"e"` but `charCode` for everything else? `key` gives you keyboard-independent values for `"."`, `"-"`, and `" "`, too.

Comment: What event are you using?

Comment: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/javascript-keycode-list-keypress-event-key-codes/ Check this if you find something helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is using event.charCode, which does not exist.

event.which.charCode does. Also you do not tell us what event.
There are keypress, keydown, keyup, input and some do not set some of the expected event values

**[Tested on Android and iOS using browserstack](https://codesandbox.io/s/ancient-water-55gm8?file=/src/App.js)**

Only one that seems to work in React on Android

```js
export default function App() {
  const handleInput = (event) => {
    // eslint-disable-next-line
    event.target.value = event.target.value.replace(/[e\.\- ]/g, "");
    console.log(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input type="number" onInput={handleInput} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

### Older answers

**Keydown and the code names which is recommended**

```js
document.getElementById("positiveIntOnly").addEventListener("keydown",function(e) {
  // block e char, dot, hyphen and spacebar
  if (["KeyE", "Period", "Minus", "Space"].includes(e.code)) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(e.code);
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="number" id="positiveIntOnly" />
```

**Or as mentioned by TJ, e.key:**

```js
document.getElementById("positiveIntOnly").addEventListener("keydown",function(e) {
  // block e char, dot, hyphen and spacebar
  if ("e.- ".includes(e.key)) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(e.key);
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="number" id="positiveIntOnly" />
```

**Set a min and max and use a regexp to handle paste**

```html
<input type="number" id="positiveIntOnly" min="0" max="999" step="1" 
oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[e\.\- ]/g,'')" />
```

Comment: FWIW, `["e", ".", "-", " "].includes(e.key)` also works.

Comment: Sure -- I was just allowing for future expansion (`"Enter"`, for instance).

Comment: Assuming a number or textfield, I would wrap in a form and use the submit event to handle enter. I would likely never handle enter in a form field

Comment: That was just an example, as you undoubtedly know.

Comment: `"ArrowLeft"`, `"ArrowRight"` (etc.), `"Delete"`, `"Insert"`, `"Home"`/`"End"`, function keys, ... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key/Key_Values

Comment: These is still not working in mobile keypad ? any idea on this

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-brook-z02uk

Comment: If you @mplungjan @ tj if you open the codesandbox link which I have shared on above in mobile phone, then you are free to enter all the characters (dot, hiphen, space) how can we block this in mobile virtual keyboard ?

Comment: In android i am able to

Comment: I had already mentioned on the question, this part
But when I access on mobile I think I am not able to get the right key code.

Comment: yes i had checked , so what will be right solution which can be used across browser and mobile

Comment: Yep none of them worked on android which I tried on my mobile https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-brook-z02uk

Comment: i think you can use browserstack to verify this, I hope since it simulates the same as like mobile

Comment: whats the issue, i could help within my knowledge

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-brook-z02uk @mplungjan you are referring to this isn't, still same not working In android

Comment: can you share it, so i will check it on android and will update here

Comment: I recreated it and tested it in browserstack. At least the last works https://codesandbox.io/s/ancient-water-55gm8?file=/src/App.js on a galaxy

Comment: Yep, so how to make this working in android, I think the current solutions won't work

Comment: Okay i haven't seen the updated answer let me check it

Comment: I also found out why your code does not even work on any other device. Please reload the answer

Comment: i tried the same logic on onChange but it was not working, whats the difference of onInput and onChange ?

Comment: On some devices onchange triggers after the field is blurred. oninput triggers on paste too, which makes it more interesting

Comment: @mplungjan i had one doubt https://codesandbox.io/s/ancient-water-55gm8?file=/src/App.js, if we enter (999.) still dot i am able to enter in the third input field, how can I block that one ?

Comment: when i am entering dot it between numbers still able to enter it

Answer (score 1):

You can just you the `key` property:

```js
["e" ,"E", "-", ".", " "].includes(e.key)
```

[You're not supposed to use the `charCode` property as it is deprecated.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/charCode)

Comment: Heh, I just mentioned this in a comment on the other answer...

Comment: hmmm I'm just wondering if that wouldn't result in some kind of a little lag ? 
Just curious, never used this.  but it feels like it would result in the letter being typed in the input and then eventually being removed, 
instead of actually being prevented from appearing. @T.J.Crowder but please correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: @Kiruna theres the `beforeinput` event, but I think the support is not great.

Comment: @nullptr oh, interesting. will give it a shot next time around 

Comment: @nullptr this doesn't works on android, as the questions says, I am looking for both browser and mobile it should work. Any idea on how to make this working in mobile ?